# Yii2 MongoDB delete single row from document

Tags: mongodb, yii2

I try this two way to delete but unable to do so:--

Try one:-

```
$query = new Query();
$query->delete()->from('table_name')->where(['disease_id' => 'A0PO919Q-12', 'status' => 1]);
```

Try Two:-

```
$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('table_name');
$collection->delete(['disease_id' => 'A0PO919Q-12']);
```

Can anyone try to delete data from mongo DB in Yii2 Framewrok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution

```
$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('table_name');
$collection->remove(['disease_id' => 'A0PO919Q-12']);
```